# Why do living tissues need to be moist for oxygen to diffuse across them?

Tags: biophysics, diffusion

If an earthworm's skin dries out, oxygen can't diffuse across its skin any more and the worm suffocates and dies. Why does the skin have to be moist to allow oxygen to diffuse across? If there is oxygen in some water or mucus next to the skin, and that oxygen diffuses across the skin, how is that physically different from having oxygen in some air next to the skin?

I tried asking this on [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65342/why-does-a-worms-skin-need-to-be-wet-for-oxygen-to-diffuse-across-it/65459#65459), to no avail.

Comment: No avail?? Wow: I'm stunned! Well, hopefully there is a chemist here that can answer this great question.

Comment: WetSavannaAnimal, given your user name, isn't this your time to shine?

Comment: Isn't this simply due to the mucus layer becoming hard when it dries out?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's a universal rule that small animals that don't have lungs and rely on diffusion for oxygen have to have moist skins because I don't think that most insects have moist skins but they can get oxygen by diffusion just fine. So answering this question would seem to require a bit of knowledge about the specific physiology of worms and related animals rather than a general knowledge of physics.

Comment: @SamuelWeir insects don't breathe through their skin. They breathe through something called tracheoles, and the diffusion into the body happens at a liquid/gas interface. https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/fact-files/respiration.html

Comment: The skin cells of an earthworm are going to be composed of 65% (or more) of water.  If the water content gets much below this, I have no doubt that those skin cells will die.  Because of the way the earthworm exchanges oxygen with the environment, the skin cells are actively involved in oxygen transport, so they must be alive to do their job.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to consider that gasses can diffuse throughout liquids but not really throughout solids, so I don't this it is a matter of having liquid as a form of transport, but to acknowledge that if it were to dry out, it would form a physical barrier (far more dense and static than liquid) which would prevent the diffusion of gas, but that is just my guess.